# Grails - How to cache service method with grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria as parameter?

Tags: caching, grails, service

I have a service method as given below, that uses `grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria` as its parameter. Since this method is called frequently, i want to cache this method. But in this case, i get a hit on db, every time the method is called. I use grails "Cache plugin"

```
@Cacheable("totalCountCache")
public int count(DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria) throws Exception {
    return detachedCriteria.count();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focus of this question should be towards the parameter of function, `DetachedCriteria`. There is no way, (as far as i know) that a `DetachedCriteria` be used as a key.

Luckily for me, i had another object 'UserCriteria'(this is a custom object, that i created) which was used to create `DetachedCriteria`. so i updated the method so that it would accept my 'UserCriteria' object as parameter. Shown below

```
@Cacheable(value='userTotalCountCache', key='#userCriteria.toString()')
public int count(UserCriteria userCriteria) throws Exception {
    DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = getDetachedCriteria(userCriteria);
    return detachedCriteria.count();
}
```

And it worked.

PS : For this to work, i had to override the toString() of the `UserCriteria`, since that is used as the key here.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a key, then the following default key generation strategy will be used:

```
public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object… params) {

   if (params.length == 1) {
      return (params[0] == null ? 53 : params[0]);
   }

   if (params.length == 0) { return 0; }

   int hashCode = 17; 

   for (Object object : params) { 
      hashCode = 31 * hashCode + (object == null ? 53 : object.hashCode()); 
   } 
   return hashCode; 
}
```

As your method only has a single parameter, the `detachedCriteria` itself will be used as the key, so the cache will be missed if:

- you call this method with a unique `detachedCriteria` object (one that hasn't been encountered before)
- you call this method with a `detachedCriteria` that has been encountered before, but the value cached for this object has expired

If this key generation strategy is not appropriate, you can override it by defining a spring bean named `webCacheKeyGenerator` that implements the `grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.WebKeyGenerator` interface (you can subclass `DefaultWebKeyGenerator` to simplify implementing this interface).